# Python How to set multiple schedules for time range and execute at set interval

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

Firstly. I'm NOT well versed in python at all.
What I need is the following:

I have multiple time ranges that need to execute a function at a set interval after said function has been executed. This should only run Mon->Fri on Emphasis on "after said function has executed.

So for arguments sake:

**functionname:** checkdata
**time1 execution range:** 10h00->12h00
**time2 execution range:** 14h00->16h00
**time to wait after executing function (checkdata) before executing it again :** 60s
**days to execute:** Mon.,Tues....up to and inclu Fri

Now I know about the python scheduler and what I have so far is:

schedule.every(60).monday.at("10:00").to("12:00").do(checkdata)
schedule.every(60).monday.at("14:00").to("16:00").do(checkdata)
..
repeat above until (and including friday)

However I read the docsand in there it says the following about "to()" : Schedule the job to run at an irregular (randomized) interval.

I dont need it to run randomly.. I need the job to run in 60s intervals after it finished the previous run of the job all within the scheduled time range